# R: Avoiding loops by finding A data.table equivalent of using dataframe [a : b] notation

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

I am an advanced beginner in **R** who works on large insurance claims datasets.

**DESIRED ADVICE** I've just raised the speed of a particular script written by my team by ~500-fold. But I'd love to hear your thoughts on getting more speed using the `data.table` package.

**BACKGROUND** Each purchase of medication in our insurance database is encoded as a row containing a de-identified `member_id` and the `startdate` of said prescription. We need to record the length of time between each purchase of a given drug. Such `inbetween` times are simply the difference between the `startdate` of the prescription and that of the next one that the member bought.

**CURRENT APPROACH** `base` functions that avoid loops are favored by subsetting our main `Claims` dataframe/datatable using dataframe-friendly `[a : b]` notation. It is this notation that I am having difficulty executing using the `data.table` package, which I really want to use because of its speed. This script already takes ~25 sec to process a smaller dataset with ~3 million prescriptions for ~600,000 patients; our bigger datasets can be 10 times larger. I am worried about non-linear scaling.

Basically, most `inbetween` values are calculated easily by subtracting one row in a presorted dataframe from the preceding row. This approach requires the last prescription of each member to be corrected, however, depending on whether that prescription is also the first prescription for that member (*i.e.*, the member has only one prescription). We therefore first define `Claims$firstofmember` and `Claims$lastofmember`, then proceed with the proper way of calculating `in-between`:

```
  library(data.table)
  Claims[order(member_id, startdate)]
  Claims$inbetween[1 : (nrow(Claims) - 1)] <- Claims$startdate[2 : nrow(Claims)] 
                               - Claims$startdate[1 : (nrow(Claims) - 1)] 

  Claims$firstofmember <- "Y"
  Claims$firstofmember[2 : nrow(Claims)] <- 
       ifelse(Claims$member_id[2 : nrow(Claims)] != 
       Claims$member_id[1 : (nrow(Claims) - 1)], "Y", "N")
  Claims$lastofmember <- "Y"
  Claims$lastofmember[1 : (nrow(Claims) - 1)] <- 
       ifelse(Claims$member_id[2 : nrow(Claims)] != 
       Claims$member_id[1 : (nrow(Claims) - 1)], "Y", "N")

 Claims$inbetween <- 0
 Claims$inbetween[1 : (nrow(Claims) - 1)] <- Claims$startdate[2 : nrow(Claims)] - 
       Claims$startdate[1 : (nrow(Claims) - 1)]
 Claims$inbetween[Claims$firstofmember == "Y" & Claims$lastofmember == "Y"]   
       <- round(pmax(Claims$ltvdate[Claims$firstofmember == "Y" &        
       Claims$lastofmember == "Y"], Claims$enddate[Claims$firstofmember == 
       "Y" & Claims$lastofmember == "Y"])) -  
       Claims$startdate[Claims$firstofmember == "Y" & Claims$lastofmember == 
       "Y"]
 Claims$inbetween[Claims$firstofmember == "N" & Claims$lastofmember == "Y"] 
       <- Claims$enddate[Claims$firstofmember == "N" & Claims$lastofmember 
       == "Y"] - Claims$startdate[Claims$firstofmember == "N" &  
       Claims$lastofmember == "Y"]
```

**SESSION INFO**

```
 R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14)
 Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
 Running under: OS X 10.11 (El Capitan)

 locale:
 [1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

 attached base packages:
  [1] grid      stats4    parallel  stats     graphics  grDevices utils               datasets  methods   base     

 other attached packages:
  [1] XVector_0.10.0       BiocInstaller_1.20.1 RColorBrewer_1.1-2   gplots_2.17.0        RPostgreSQL_0.4      DBI_0.3.1           
  [7] zoo_1.7-12           stringr_1.0.0        fields_8.3-5         maps_3.0.0-2         spam_1.3-0           shiny_0.12.2        
 [13] zipcode_1.0          visreg_2.2-0         plyr_1.8.3           IRanges_2.4.1        S4Vectors_0.8.2      BiocGenerics_0.16.1 
 [19] dplyr_0.4.3          data.table_1.9.6    

 loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.2        bitops_1.0-6       tools_3.2.2        zlibbioc_1.16.0    digest_0.6.8       jsonlite_0.9.17    lattice_0.20-33   
 [8] gtools_3.5.0       caTools_1.17.1     R6_2.1.1           gdata_2.17.0       magrittr_1.5       htmltools_0.2.6    assertthat_0.1    
 [15] mime_0.4           xtable_1.8-0       httpuv_1.3.3       KernSmooth_2.23-15 stringi_1.0-1      lazyeval_0.1.10    chron_2.3-47
```

Answer (score 0):

Using diff() and `by` in the data.table should give you what you're looking for:

```
setkey(Claims, member_id, startdate)
Claims[,inbetween:=c(NA,diff(startdate)), by=member_id]
```

The setkey() ensures the ordering works correctly and improve the grouping speed.

Inserting `NA` ahead of the diff results handles the 1 prescription case and ensures you have the trailing gap not the leading gap between prescriptions.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, Stephen Zander, for your reply.

I tested Stephen's suggestion on the dataset I mentioned in my original problem, whose ~3 million rows for ~600,000 patients could be processed in ~25 sec.

While I found out that Stephen's suggestion mysteriously decelerated my script by ~10-fold relative to my previous version, I was inspired by his reference to `setkey()`. By using keys to help merge my main `Claims` and auxiliary `LTVTable` data.tables, I sped my script by ~3-fold relative to my previous version. Here is my script as it stands:

```
  > system.time({
  +   LTVTable <- LTVTable[, .(member_id, mincorsdate, maxcoredate)]
  +   LTVTable <- LTVTable[order(member_id, mincorsdate, maxcoredate)]
  +   setkey(LTVTable, member_id)
  +   setkey(Claims, member_id)
  +   Claims <- Claims[LTVTable]
  +   Claims <- as.data.frame(Claims)
  +   Claims$mincorsdate <- as.Date(Claims$mincorsdate, origin = "1970-01-01")
  +   Claims$maxcoredate <- as.Date(Claims$maxcoredate, origin = "1970-01-01")
  +   Claims$ltvdate <- as.Date(Claims$mincorsdate + ltv, origin = "1970-01-01")
  +   
  +   Claims$firstofmember <- "Y"
  +   Claims$firstofmember[2 : nrow(Claims)] <- ifelse(Claims$member_id[2 : nrow(Claims)] != Claims$member_id[1 : (nrow(Claims) - 1)], "Y", "N")
  +   Claims$lastofmember <- "Y"
  +   Claims$lastofmember[1 : (nrow(Claims) - 1)] <- ifelse(Claims$member_id[2 : nrow(Claims)] != Claims$member_id[1 : (nrow(Claims) - 1)], "Y", "N")
  +     
  +   Claims$inbetween <- 0
  +   Claims$inbetween[1 : (nrow(Claims) - 1)] <- Claims$startdate[2 : nrow(Claims)] - Claims$startdate[1 : (nrow(Claims) - 1)]
  +   Claims$inbetween[Claims$firstofmember == "Y" & Claims$lastofmember == "Y"] <- round(pmax(Claims$ltvdate[Claims$firstofmember == "Y" & Claims$lastofmember == "Y"], Claims$enddate[Claims$firstofmember == "Y" & Claims$lastofmember == "Y"])) - Claims$startdate[Claims$firstofmember == "Y" & Claims$lastofmember == "Y"]
  +   Claims$inbetween[Claims$firstofmember == "N" & Claims$lastofmember == "Y"] <- Claims$enddate[Claims$firstofmember == "N" & Claims$lastofmember == "Y"] - Claims$startdate[Claims$firstofmember == "N" & Claims$lastofmember == "Y"]
  +   
  +   Claims$inbetween2 <- 0
  +   Claims$inbetween2[1 : (nrow(Claims) - 1)] <- Claims$startdate[2 :      nrow(Claims)] - Claims$startdate[1 : (nrow(Claims) - 1)]
  +   Claims$inbetween2[Claims$firstofmember == "Y" & Claims$lastofmember == "Y"] <- Claims$enddate[Claims$firstofmember == "Y" & Claims$lastofmember == "Y"] - Claims$startdate[Claims$firstofmember == "Y" & Claims$lastofmember == "Y"]
  +   Claims$inbetween2[Claims$firstofmember == "N" & Claims$lastofmember == "Y"] <- Claims$inbetween[Claims$firstofmember == "N" & Claims$lastofmember == "Y"]
  + })
  user  system elapsed 
  8.003   1.497   9.582
```

Would love to hear any other thoughts floating out there. I myself am working on data.table equivalents for the code lines that start with
 `Claims$inbetweenN[Claims$firstofmember == "X" & Claims$lastofmember == "Y"]`